# How to fix view position after moving it

Tags: android, android-animation

With the code below, the `TextView` variable `tvAppName` slides up successfully, but after 1,200 milliseconds the view goes back to its position. How can I fix the view after moving it?

```
        Handler hd = new Handler();
        hd.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 100, 0);
                anim.setDuration(500);
                anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });
                tvAppName.startAnimation(anim);
            }
        }, 1200);
    }
```

Comment: set setFillAfter() to true.

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/12/android-animations-explained.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use anim.setfillafter(true)

> the transformation that this animation performed will persist when it
>   is finished

If you did not use code below.you can **Delete** That

```
anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation: You need use [setFillAfter](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setFillAfter(boolean)) method.

```
anim.setFillAfter( true );
```

> If fillAfter is true, the transformation that this animation performed
>   will persist when it is finished

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [NineOldAndroid](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids) library. This is a really good library. It will help you with a lot of animations.

Comment: Actually I checked that out already. But it seems deprecated.

Comment: It means this library is no more supported or you can say no more changes are going to happen in this library. You can still use it. By the way which SDK version are you using?

Comment: I currently set the SDK version at 23

Comment: you should not use deprecated methods or libraries: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html

Comment: If you SDK version is 23 then you are good to go without this library. I will edit my answer later for translate animation. This library is basically for older android versions.